# How to capture a midi performance and apply a vst plugin to it?

Tags: midi, vst

I am looking for the most inexpensive way to accomplish the following tasks:

1) Record a midi performance including pitch bends into a sequencer program (pc or mac) that provides a click, has the ability to quantize as it records, and allows me to move notes around later with some kind of GUI.

2) Apply a vst plugin to this midi performance with the pitch bends intact. (and then of course render a wav or mp3)

I have the following and software: pc, mac, several keyboards that can be midi controllers, several vst plugins.

I would like the absolute simplest solution, but I'm willing to buy some software.

Thanks so much for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Having real time recording quantizing, "offline" editing and VSTi support in one application rules out most of the simple solutions I know of. I'm afraid you have to invest a tiny bit of manual studying and setup here.

Two solutions come to my mind:

1. [Reaper](http://www.reaper.fm/) - lots of functionality - it will do all of it.
2. [Ardour](http://ardour.org/) - unsure about the real time quantizing, but it has "offline" quantizing for sure.

And a third a bit out of scope option regarding complexity: [Max-For-Live](https://www.ableton.com/en/live/max-for-live/) - it will let you set up quite complex stuff, both for processing the MIDI data and transforming that into sound. Designed for live performance.

Comment: I do not need the solution to be in one application. I'm happy to capture the midi performance in one app, edit it in another app, and then apply the vst plugin in another. Does that open up other low-complexity solutions?

Comment: You could take a look at Cakewalk Music Creator. It is simple. I'm not sure if it has the quantizing stuff though.

Answer (score -1):

try tunafish that should still be available on archive.org

https://web.archive.org/web/20120121112513/http://www.brambos.com/archive.html

Comment: This post doesn't really explain how tunafish does, or how it works. If you can edit your post with more information, that would be helpful.